# Upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: upgrade, drivers, graphics, webcam

I have installed 10.04 in june 2010 and last time while updating I messed up with my graphics driver.

I am not able to apply the extra visual effects and also yet I am unable to find out driver for my motion eye webcam. I tried "cheese" but not succeed it shows no device found.

My question is that can upgrading to 10.10 solve my problem. If yes then please tell me that should I have to fresh installation or not?

I have a **Sonyvaio VGN CR 363 Laptop** with **ATI Radeon x2300**.

Answer (score 5):

There is no easy way for anyone to answer the question, unless they have the exact same hardware.

A quicker way would be to [download the Ubuntu 10.10 cd](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download) and test it in a **Live environment** (it's option 3 , select the "Show me how" ). This way you can test it yourself, *and be sure,* without making any changes to your install.

As for the webcam, cheese is just a software which views your webcam video input. Whether the webcam is detected or not depends on the kernel and if the driver has been included for your webcam model.

Comment: i am going to test it soon after ma exam ends!!!